# Importing external xml file into flash

Tags: xml, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am creating a flash site that loads in external information via an xml file that was given to us by our lecturer to use.  In the flash sample we were given the xml imports fine, loading the images and text from the xml file onto the page, but when I copy the exact layers and paste them into the scene of my site, only the images load.  I have saved my flash site in the exact same place as the sample site, with the xml file saved in the same directory.  This is the actionscript code in flash:

```
mediaFolder = "book/";
//
xmlObject = new XML();
xmlObject.onLoad = readMedia;
xmlObject.ignoreWhite = true;
xmlObject.load("book.xml");
//
stop();
//
function readMedia(success) {
if (success == true) {
    // Root node
    rootNode = xmlObject.firstChild;
    // Size of book/CD collection = number of child nodes
    sizeOfCollection = rootNode.childNodes.length;
    // Current node = first child node
    currentNode = rootNode.firstChild;
    // Display next book/CD.
    drawItem();
}
}
function drawItem() {
// Title
title.text = currentNode.childNodes[0].firstChild;
// Author
authorName.text = currentNode.childNodes[1].firstChild;
// Load in external JPEG of book/CD cover
coverImage.loadMovie(mediaFolder + currentNode.childNodes[2].firstChild);
// Book price and currency symbol
bookPrice.text = currentNode.childNodes[4].attributes.currency + " " +           currentNode.childNodes[4].firstChild;
//
debug();
}
//
nextBook.onRelease = function() {
nextNode = currentNode.nextSibling;
if (nextNode == null) {
    break;
} else {
    currentNode = nextNode;
    drawItem();
}
};
//
previousBook.onRelease = function() {
nextNode = currentNode.previousSibling;
if (nextNode == null) {
    break;
} else {
    currentNode = nextNode;
    drawItem();
}
};
// Read books XML file.
books.onRelease = function() {
xmlFile = "book.xml";
mediaFolder = "book/";
xmlObject.load(xmlFile);
};
// Read music XML file.
music.onRelease = function() {
xmlFile = "music.xml";
mediaFolder = "music/";
xmlObject.load(xmlFile);
};
/*
Display debugging information about each XML node,
into fields on the right side of the screen.
*/
function debug() {
debugCurrentNode = currentNode;
debugCurrentNodeChildNodes = currentNode.childNodes;
debugCurrentNodeChildNodes0 = currentNode.childNodes[0];
debugCurrentNodeChildNodes0child = currentNode.childNodes[0].firstChild;
debugCurrentNodeChildNodes1 = currentNode.childNodes[1];
debugCurrentNodeChildNodes1child = currentNode.childNodes[1].firstChild;
}
```

The code is right because it loads in the sample flash site.  Here is one of the xml files it is loading in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<BOOK_COLLECTION>
<BOOK>
    <TITLE>Hi</TITLE>
    <AUTHOR>Jon Wozencroft</AUTHOR>
    <BOOKCOVER>brody.jpg</BOOKCOVER>
    <ISBN>00-456754674-11</ISBN>
    <PRICE Currency="$">44.25</PRICE>
</BOOK>
<BOOK>
    <TITLE>Actionscript using Flash MX</TITLE>
    <AUTHOR>Colin Moock</AUTHOR>
    <BOOKCOVER>asdg.jpg</BOOKCOVER>
    <ISBN>00-4567-65785-11</ISBN>
    <PRICE Currency="$">24.50</PRICE>
</BOOK>
<BOOK>
    <TITLE>The Design Of Everyday Things</TITLE>
    <AUTHOR>Donald Norman</AUTHOR>
    <BOOKCOVER>norman.jpg</BOOKCOVER>
    <ISBN>00-477754674-11</ISBN>
    <PRICE Currency="$">16.50</PRICE>
</BOOK>
<BOOK>
    <TITLE>Maeda@Media</TITLE>
    <AUTHOR>John Maeda</AUTHOR>
    <BOOKCOVER>media.jpg</BOOKCOVER>
    <ISBN>00-422567-65785-11</ISBN>
    <PRICE Currency="$">17.00</PRICE>
</BOOK>
</BOOK_COLLECTION>
```

Answer (score 0):

well, first of all, i would ask your lecturer as it is really hard to guess what is going on by not knowing your environment

but since the images are being loaded and text not, then my first guess is that you have simply not embedded the font used by the textfield to which you assign the dynamic text from the xml.

are you using adobe flash ide? if you do, you can embed the fonts by simply clicking on the textfield and then hitting "embed" button. of course, embed the fonts which are going to be used by the text field...